# Saved Search with Time Criteria

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

**Use-Case** : *I am having an Integration in place that creates multiple Vendor Bills in Netsuite for every 5 minutes. I want to export the vendor bills created in those time to FTP. For that I need to create a saved search that can preview vendor bills created in past five minutes. Do we have any criteria in Netsuite Save Search to accomplish that ?*

**Please advise.**

Answer (score 0):

A Netsuite inconsistency.

I keep a snippet for this.

```js
function toNSLegalDatetime(date){
    var formatted = <string>format.format({value:date, type:format.Type.DATETIMETZ});
    return formatted.replace(/(:\d{2}):\d{2}/, '$1');
}
```

Then you can do:

```
const lastDT = new Date(Date.now() - 5*60000)); // 5 minutes ago
        search.create({
            type:'vendorbill',
            filters:[
                search.createFilter({name:'datecreated', operator:search.Operator.ONORAFTER, values:toNSLegalDatetime(lastDT)}),
                ...
```

BUT

timing like this is very tricky because small delays in timing could cause you to miss transactions. If you can keep track of the last internalid reported your next search could just use that and it wouldn't matter what the lag was.

```
search.createFilter({name:'internalidnumber', operator:search.Operator.GREATERTHAN, values:lastIdReported})
```